# LINQ query gone wrong

Tags: linq, sorting, c#-4.0

I have a class Card that holds a reference to an enum with different Card types.  The enum is defined as follows:

```
 enum Rank
    {
        Ace = 1,
        Two,
        Three,
        Four,
        Five,
        Six,
        Seven,
        Eight,
        Nine,
        Ten,
        Jack,
        King,
        Queen
    }
```

I have a LINQ Query that is supposed to take a List and check if they are in sequence. So that means the difference between any two ranks is only 1.

Query:

```
List<Card> cards = group.ToList();
cards.Sort(SortComparatorByRank);
List<Card> test = cards.Where((x, idx) =>
            (idx >= 1 && (int)cards[idx - 1].CardRank == (int)x.CardRank - 1 ||
            (idx < cards.Count() - 1 &&
            (int)cards[idx + 1].CardRank == (int)x.CardRank + 1))).ToList();
```

However running this, I get this result:
[image: items in list after running query...]

As you can see, Two and Four supposedly follow each other???

The list given to this query does not contain all cards, thats why I need to check the ranking order, etc...

Comment: I think your linq code isn't very readable. I'd prefer simple imperative code over your linq code.

Comment: As a side note, your `Card` class doesn't hold a reference to the enum, enum's are value types so `Card` simply *holds* the enum (nitpicking for sure). Also it looks like you've reversed `King` and `Queen` in your `Rank` enum although I can't say if it's intended or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that doesn't show that Two and Four supposedly follow each other. It suggests that Three wasn't present in `cards`.

`Two` passes the first part of the filter due to `Ace` coming before it, and `Four` passes the second part of the filter due to `Five` coming after it.

Given that you're trying to check whether everything's in sequence, it sounds like you really want something returning a `bool` - for which I'd suggest `All`. You also only want them pairwise, so I'd consider something like:

```
var valid = cards.Zip(cards.Skip(1), (first, second) => new { first, second })
                 .All(pair => pair.first.CardRank == pair.second.CardRank - 1);
```

Comment: +1 for `cards.Zip(cards.Skip(1), (first, second) => new { first, second })`, this is beautiful.

Comment: Could I use zip to compare 3 elements?

Comment: @Tony: You'd need to call Zip twice: `list.Zip(list.Skip(1), ...).Zip(list.Skip(2))`

Answer (score 0):

```
 (idx < cards.Count() - 1 &&
 (int)cards[idx + 1].CardRank == (int)x.CardRank + 1))).ToList();
```

He is pairing the four with the five.

Answer (score 0):

On your call to cards.Sort, you are performing the sort, but not setting the new list back to the cards pointer.

Try doing a cards = cards.Sort (on the second line of your code).

Comment: Do not confuse (IEnumerable<T>) Enumerable<T>.OrderBy and (void) List<T>.Sort http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx